# Convert DateTime for MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, datetime, datetime-conversion

I want to change the DateTime for MySQL in C#.

My MySQL database only accept this format `1976-04-09 22:10:00`.

In C# have a string who have a date value:

```
string str = "12-Apr-1976 22:10";
```

I want to convert for MySQL then it look like:

```
1976-04-12 22:10
```

How I can change them or how other programmer do this by using `dd mm hh yy` method? Can anyone tell me about them?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can hard-code ISO format

```
string formatForMySql = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

or use next:

```
// just to shorten the code
var isoDateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;

// "1976-04-12T22:10:00"
dateValue.ToString(isoDateTimeFormat.SortableDateTimePattern); 

// "1976-04-12 22:10:00Z"    
dateValue.ToString(isoDateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern)
```

and so on

Comment: hh:mm is 12hr format, you'll need HH:mm. I just updated my code with that section

Comment: Great answer! Small syntactical error: DataTimeFormat should be DateTimeFormat.

Comment: Do not pass dates to MySQL like this. Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/28925999/34092 instead.

Comment: In case the `SortableDateTimePattern` is not found on `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat` try using `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.SortableDateTimePattern`

Answer (score 17):

If your string format for the DateTime is fixed you can convert to the `System.DateTime` using:

```
string myDate = "12-Apr-1976 22:10";
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(myDate);
```

Now, when you need it in your specific format, you can then reverse the process, i.e.:

```
string formatForMySql = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

edit - updated code. For some strange reason DateTime.ParseExact wasnt playing nice.

Comment: btw, your code doesn't work out of the box, I don't know why. However just `DateTime.Parse` works properly

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly suggest you use parameterized queries instead of sending values as strings in the first place.

That way you only need to be able to convert your input format to `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`, and then you don't need to worry about the database format. This is not only simpler, but avoids SQL injection attacks (e.g. for string values) and is more robust in the face of database settings changes.

For the original conversion to a `DateTime`, I suggest you use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` to explicitly specify the expected format.

Comment: With my experience with MySQL, probably because of collation settings, it not always accepts `System.DateTime` and the best way to guarantee proper work on any server is explicitly convert date to string in format `yyyy-MM-dd ..`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1.Extract date from oracle data base and pass it to variable

```
 string lDat_otp = "";

  if (rw_mat["dat_otp"].ToString().Length <= 0)
  {
      lDat_otp = "";
  }
  else
  {
      lDat_otp = rw_mat["dat_otp"].ToString();
  }
```

2.Conversion to mysql format

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(lDat_otp);
string formatForMySql = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

3.Pass formatForMySql variable to procedure or to something else