# DateTime from C# to MySQL: incomplete storage

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql, datetime

I am working with `DateTime` objects to create a monitoring application.
The principle is that each time a user launches a specific application, the current date and time will be saved in the DB. Then in the monitoring app, I get this date field from DB and display it.

As I went through testing today, I tried to launch the app : `DateTime.Now` is stored (ie, in French culture, 22/04/11 17:09:50 ).
When I launch the monitoring app, what I get from the database is 22/04/11 00:00:00
Is there any reason why the exact time isn't saved?

The column in DB is, of course, a Date column.

Some code:

Storing the date:

```
                command = new MySqlCommand(_updateDateCommand, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Template", app);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Date", DateTime.Now);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Id", u.Id);


                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0) return true;
```

Retrieving the data:

```
                object date = reader.GetValue(4);
                if (date == System.DBNull.Value)
                {
                    tempUserApp.DateLastUsed = DateTime.MinValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    tempUserApp.DateLastUsed = (DateTime)date;
                }
```

I'm sure that the problem comes from the storing process, because visualizing data with a tool such as Toad show me `22/04/11 00:00:00` in the Date field.

Update command:

```
private readonly string _updateDateCommand =
            "UPDATE userapplications " +
            "JOIN template t ON t.Name = ?Template " +
            "SET DateUsed=?Date  WHERE `User Id`=?Id AND `Template Id`=t.Id";
```

Is there any special formatting for MySQL dates?

I bumped into [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633262/convert-datetime-for-mysql-using-c) and tried the solution proposed, it does not work either

Any idea?

Comment: Could you show the _updateCommand contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DB Column should be DateTime, not Date. Look at the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).

About DATE:

> The DATE type is used when you need 
>   only a date value, without a time
>   part. MySQL retrieves and displays
>   DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.
>   The supported range is '1000-01-01' to
>   '9999-12-31'.

About DATETIME:

> The DATETIME type is used when you
>   need values that contain both date and
>   time information. MySQL retrieves and
>   displays DATETIME values in
>   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01
>   00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Getting the Date return like dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00 is misleading, it's just being formatted by the tool as the default date/datetime format. What you really need is to set the DB column as DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type in your DataBase, it seems to me your field is a Date type,
so