# C# MySQL LINQ DateTime conversion

Tags: c#, mysql, date

I'm trying to retrieve records from a mySQL DB using LINQ and C#.

The date in c# code is a string: 23-01-2010

I need to convert this to DateTime format as 2010-01-23 (mySQL default  DateTime format), otherwise the query does not return any records, at present it errors saying a string cannot be matched against a DateTime (row.DateOfIssue)
If I convert the string to DateTime (C#), then it is not in the mySQL DateTime format of yyyy-MM-dd

```
String endDate = "23-01-2010"; 
var query = (from row in uow.UserPersonalLicenseDetails
                             where (endDate >= row.DateOfIssue && endDate <= row.DateOfExpiry)
                             select row)
```

This is such a standard query it seems mad that it is so hard to do in LINQ.
It seems putting any method like CompareTo etc in the where clause causes an error of "Search for a class that works in this scenario"

I'm now wondering if the best line of attack might be to write a stored procedure in the database.  This could then take the C# datetime as a parameter, convert it to mySQL format and then run the required query.....
Any thoughts?

Comment: this may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633262/convert-datetime-for-mysql-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Make it a DateTime - so

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
```

Then

```
myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

---------- or this:

```
    var myDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate); 
var query = (from row in uow.UserPersonalLicenseDetails 
where ((myDate.CompareTo(row.DateOfIssue)>=0 && (myDate.CompareTo(row.DateOfExpiry)<=0) 
select row
```

Comment: This gives the error: "Operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type String and System.DateTime

Comment: this does?: 
String endDate = "23-01-2010"; 
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
var query = (from row in uow.UserPersonalLicenseDetails 
                             where (myDate >= row.DateOfIssue && myDate <= row.DateOfExpiry) 
                             select row)

Comment: how about this:
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
var query = (from row in uow.UserPersonalLicenseDetails 
                             where ((myDate.CompareTo(row.DateOfIssue)>=0 && (myDate.CompareTo(row.DateOfExpiry)<=0) 
                             select row

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your date string to `DateTime` and then in the LINQ convert the string to `DateTime` that's coming back in order to do the comparison. I've used `ParseExact` because we need to make sure that we are parsing to the exact format that MySQL stores the date in, which is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm`.

Something like:

```
var endDate = DateTime.Parse("23-10-2010").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
var formattedEndDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
//you could cut that to one line by putting the date in said format in the first place

var query = (from row in uow.UserPersonalLicenseDetails
             where formattedEndDate >= row.DateOfIssue
                 && formattedEndDate <= row.DateOfExpiry
             select row)
```

Comment: this looks promising, however, ParseExact expects the first parmaeter to be of String, but row.DateOfIssue is a Date in the database......thx

Comment: Ah I thought they were strings, updated my answer to reflect :)

Comment: I don't think this will work.  ParseExact expects the format of parameter 1 to be exactly the same as specified by parameter 2.

Comment: Edited! Yeah sorry, it needs to be parsed to string with that format, then parsed again (you could cut this out by just doing `var endDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-10-23 00:00");`, but if your end date is going to be a parameter passed in, then I guess it's easier to do it the way I've done it in the edit :)

Comment: Sorry, this won't work as the second parse converts the date back to C# format, rather than keeping it in yyyy-MM-dd format....sob sob...this is very painful

Comment: Have you tried it using that code? Although it'll be in that format, when you are retrieving the dates from MySQL into your `row` objects it should automatically convert the format into one that matches the C# format?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but it seems that the SQL generated by LINQ is converting the date back to: dd/MM/yyyy format...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem was that the Table had the field defined as DATE rather than DATETIME so no match was being made.

Used DateTime.Date and the match was made.