# ASP.NET vb.net convert calendar date format in Month/Day/Year to Date object with Day/Month/Year

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, calendar, string-conversion

I have a calendar control:
`<asp:Calendar ID="cldDepartDate" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>`

And for example, if I chose 14th of March 2019, using the code below to display:
`lblTest.Text = cldDepartDate.SelectedDate.ToString()`
I got "3/14/2019 12:00:00 AM"

And now I want to convert it to "14/3/2019 12:00:00 AM" and store it into a Date object.

So far I have tried:

`Dim oDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(cldDepartDate.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

But it gives me this error:
[image]

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296433/convert-datetime-in-c-sharp-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-and-store-it-to-mysql-datetime) this can help you to achieve what you are looking at...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim dateString = "3/14/2019 12:00:00 AM"
    Dim oDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Debug.Print(oDate.ToString("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
```

Using the standard DateTime formats.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2#Formatting_dates_times