# is this a C# DateTime bug (missing minutes, hours and seconds in the 1970's).. is it bug or a feature?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

found this today:

```
 DateTime myDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("1972-12-12 12:12:12");
 Debug.WriteLine(myDateTime);    // shows '12/12/1972 12:12:12'
 String myString = myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Debug.WriteLine(myString );     // shows '1972.12.12 00:00:00'
```

minutes gone? why is that?

Comment: What do you think [`myDateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetime.date(v=vs.100).aspx) returns?

Comment: @user26676 [Here's a hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx). Picnic error, move along people.

Comment: should be `myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: not according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633262/convert-datetime-for-mysql-using-c-sharp

Comment: @user26676 How is that question pertinent to this one?

Comment: seriously... do you guys ever like other people - took <1 minute to get a flood of rage from far too many gloaters? @AdamHouldsworth ? a) read the link and b) thanks (no thanks) for the "help"

Comment: @user26676 Well, the link is about conversion from given formats, which isn't the same topic as why you are losing the time element. And my "help" was the official documentation for the `myDateTime.Date` property that you were using and expecting different output for. Your assumptions were incorrect. There is no rage from me, just a comical observation that the bug is not in the `DateTime` implementation, affectionately termed "problem in chair, not in computer". Tim has vocalised and even quoted that very same documentation link as an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the [`Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which truncates the time part here:

```
String myString = myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

So this gives the desired result:

```
String myString = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value
>   set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a `DateTime` instance to any other date, for example to check if  `myDateTimeInstance == DateTime.Today`, then you need to eliminate the time-part of the `DateTime` instance.

**That is the purpose of** `myDateTimeInstance.Date`: To return only the date, so it can be used while ignoring time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you get only the `Date` part of `DateTime`.
If you want desired value change

```
String myString = myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

to

```
String myString = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```