# How to search between two dates?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm really having a bad time when my code doesn't work. Can anybody help me on how to search between two dates using datetimepicker? I have a source code that retrieve the data from database but when I add the "between" in where clause, the data that I want to search, it won't display in datagridview. Also, I tried already putting "MM/dd/yyyy" in the tostring().

Code to retrieve data:

```
    public void showData()
    {
        string constring = "datasource = localhost;port = 3307; username = root; password =root; database = dbpetsales";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT transaction_ID as 'Transaction ID',  ProdName as 'Product Name',price as 'Price',subtotal as 'Subtotal', Date FROM dbpetsales.pos", conDataBase);
        try
        {

            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Code to retrieve data in searching between two dates:

```
    public void showData()
    {
        string constring = "datasource = localhost;port = 3307; username = root; password =root; database = dbpetsales";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT transaction_ID as 'Transaction ID',  ProdName as 'Product Name',price as 'Price',subtotal as 'Subtotal', Date FROM dbpetsales.pos where Date between '"+this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()+"' and '"+this.dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString()+"' ", conDataBase);
        try
        {

            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()` does not represent the date and time value expected by MySql. You need to use parameterized query.

Comment: There are plenty of questions https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+date+mysql on using date in MySql queries... like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925959/how-to-add-a-date-datetime-now-to-a-mysql-database-in-c-sharp. Could you please clarify why you decided to pick worst possible option to construct the query?

Comment: Clearly you need to change the datetime format as per needed in mysql default datetime format. Check if database columns are date or datetime? Convert datetime from code to mysql ready format.

Comment: Thanks Iti Tyagi it runs perfectly now Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

First, please use parameters instead of string concat in your query (to prevent sql-injection and send date as dates, no string ), just do like below:

```
MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT transaction_ID as 'Transaction ID',  ProdName as 'Product Name',price as 'Price',subtotal as 'Subtotal', Date FROM dbpetsales.pos where Date >= @date1 and Date <= @date2, conDataBase);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker2.Value);
```